# How do I sort(default sort), show 50 entries and filter each column datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortable').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0,1,2,3]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
               // var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(this.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {

                    //select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                      select.append( '<option>'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortable').DataTable({
        "order": [[1, "asc"],[0, "asc"]],
        "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"orderable": false},
                {"orderable": false},
                {"orderable": false},
                ],
                "searching": true,
                "paging":   false,
                "ordering": true,
                "info":     false
        });
} );
</script>
```

These 2 separate blocks work well individually if the other is commented out, but I don't know how I can combine them to be one block so I can achieve default sorting and drop-down filters.

The aim is to have drop-down filters on columns [0,1,2,3], default sorting and have defaults number of rows shown = 50.

```
//like so: 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortable').DataTable( {
sort by default;
set default rows shown to 50;
put filter on first 4 colmuns;
    })
})
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "two blocks" are two initializations of a DataTables object made from the same table, which is why they don't work together. The good news is that you can just combine the two into a single block and they should work together, since none of the options you're using conflict with each other (as far as I can tell). It should look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortable').DataTable( {
        pageLength: 50, //This is the option which will give you 50 rows by default
        order: [[1, "asc"],[0, "asc"]],
        columns: [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"orderable": false},
                {"orderable": false},
                {"orderable": false},
                ],
        searching: true,
        paging:   false,
        ordering: true,
        info:     false,
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0,1,2,3]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
               // var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(this.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {

                    //select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                      select.append( '<option>'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

You'll note that all I did was put the options selected in the second block into the first block and add the `pageLength` option to start the number of rows at 50. You can optionally surround the names of the options with `""` if you want, but it's unneccessary, just a preference thing (e.g. `"order"` vs `order`).

You should only ever have one DataTables initialization `.DataTable()` call in your code per page.